# Uwsgi Application cannot connect https with proxy

Tags: python, proxy, centos, uwsgi, squid

My application running with Uwsgi on the server that using proxy. The server proxy is in one network. But whenever the application trying to make https request (443), it raises an error like it cannot connect to internet.

`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.blabla.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /endpoint/v2/checkout_url (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))`

for proxy, I'm using squid for http and https. and for the client side, the proxy has been setup system-wide.

Kindly need advice from this issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: From the server OS can you get (with `wget`) the https resource? Have in mind with wget you might need `--no-check-certificate` parameter or/and `-e use_proxy=yes -e https_proxy=http://yourproxy.tld:3128`

Comment: yes I can get the resource endpoint with wget: `wget -q -O - https://api.balbla.com`

Comment: Ok on application level how do you make the request? A library like `requests` has proxy support, have you declare your proxy explicitly in your app ?

Comment: I'm not sure proxy declared in app. But I setup the proxy system-wide from os level. It's that not enough? This is the full error when the app tried to make request `Payment Invalid, HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.kredivo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /kredivo/v2/checkout_url (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))`

Comment: Well the error is explicit can't resolve your domain name. Can u add in the question the code snippet that take place in the call.

Comment: It looks like the app cannot connect to internet behind the proxy. The errors messsage still the same when I disable the squid.

Comment: Check how proxy works with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) library and adjust it to your code.